# Connecting domain name from namecheap to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, namecheap

Has anyone encountered this bug for connecting to firebase hosting with namecheap?

[image: NameCheap showing 2 A Records]
[image: Firebase finding 3 records]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm having this same exact problem right now.

Comment: you did not mention the problem!

Comment: I had the problem, solved it with the @ thingy and still resurfaced now

Answer (score 6):

You need to put "@" , in the A records for Host instead of your url(ex: devspace.co).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and spoke with both Firebase and NameCheap support.  Turns out that Firebase doesn't like to see any other addresses but it's own, and NameCheap's "URL Redirect" entry that appears to be on by default causes the extraneous A record to show up.