# Firebase "Connect Domain" to NameCheap failure

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

Trying to connect my domain from NameCheap to Firebase hosting and I keep getting this message:

> We couldn't find the A records we expected for your domain

Firebase helpfully tells me the A records it's looking for and the A records that it found.  Problem is that it appears that NameCheap adds a hidden (i.e. I can't remove it in the admin panel) A record pointing to themselves `192.64.119.107`.

The 2 A records that Firebase is looking for are listed correctly and match.  Is there anything I can do to remove the default NameCheap A record that seems to be gumming up the works?

Comment: Did you just assign the DNS records recently? It may take some time for DNS changes to propagate and be detected properly.

Comment: Been over 24hr, and my domain name routes correctly to Firebase.  Just seems like what Firebase is seeing prevents them from finishing the SSL certificate setup.

Comment: Gotcha. I just ask because it's not just whether the DNS routes correctly for you, but whether the DNS server(s) Firebase uses have had time to propagate the changes, so they see it on their end.  24 hours should be adequate for just anyone, though.

Comment: Have you checked [this question for a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979673/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-with-firebase-using-namecheap) It appears others have had DNS issues with Firebase there, and some suggestions were offered.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and went through all of the answers.  It's a similar issue but not the same.  I've now been in contact with Firebase and they say the issue is with an extraneous A Record that appears to be set and controlled by NameCheap, not in management console, waiting on a response from them now.

Comment: I did finally find this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555274/connecting-domain-name-from-namecheap-to-firebase that is exactly the same issue I'm having.

Comment: NameCheap finally got back to me, and pointed out that this IP was because of a "URL Redirect" record.  I've removed that record and everything seems to be moving forward now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!